# 'NoneType' error after applying .copy() to a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the Titanic dataset for a project.
I first created a dataframe with

```
titanic_df = pd.read_csv("titanic_data.csv")
```

and applied a few changes (fillna and so on).

Now I'd like to drop a few columns in that dataframe, but to avoid affecting my previous work I want to create a copy of this first. So I do

```
titanic_ml = titanic_df.copy().drop(['PassengerId','Name'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

and then when I try to display the info

```
titanic_ml.info()
```

I get this error message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'

If I apply .info() to my original titanic_df I have no issues.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you used `inplace=True` you made the change to the return value of `copy()` in place and returned `None`.

Also note that `drop` returns a copy and therefore, the `copy` method is unnecessary.

To fix your problem, don't use `inplace=True`

```
titanic_ml = titanic_df.drop(['PassengerId','Name'], axis=1)
```

---

***further explanation***

`titantic_df.copy()` returns a dataframe that is passed to `drop`.  `drop` subsequently returns a copy of the dataframe without the items requested to be dropped.  If you pass `inplace=True` it performs the operation to the object and returns `None` instead.  It is that `None` that you assigned to the variable `titanic_ml` and that is why you got the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'`.

Comment: Very neat explanation !

Comment: thanks a ton @piRSquared ! it solved the issue straight away :)